# navigate through hyperlinks in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

This is the website of skyscanner. After selecting flight I want to click on every 'Select button'(for $687) and then go to next page. On next page I want to click down arrow for outbound flight. Then I again I want to click select button ($715) and the again outbound flight arrow. So it goes in loop for all possible searches on all the pages possible.

[image]

This is how Downward arrow on next page is

[image]

Here is the code I have written so far
:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome( )

driver.get('https://www.skyscanner.com/transport/flights/nyca/lax/170717/170718/airfares-from-new-york-to-los-angeles-international-in-july-2017.html?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home#results')

while True:
        items=driver.find_element_by_class_name("fss-bpk-button expand-cba select-action")
        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("fss-bpk-button expand-cba select-action").click()
              for j, item2 in item
                  driver.find_element_by_class_name("leg-summary-container clearfix").click()
```

I also tried following but none worked:

```
 links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_element_by_class_name("fss-bpk-button expand-cba select-action")]
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code should work after some changes:

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.fss-bpk-button.expand-cba.select-action")]
```

Note that

1. To get list of elements you should use `find_elements_...()` instead of `find_element_...()`
2. Compound class names not allowed, so you might use search by `CSS` selector or `XPath` instead of search by `class` name if you want to use multiple class names to locate required elements

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am completely new to python so learning a lot! How should I loop it between the pages ? I don't understand it

Comment: In the same way you tried: `for link in links: driver.get(link)`... You got the list of links. You can navigate to each page to make required actions in a loop\